# ¿por qué cuando uso yt-dlp me sale el siguiente error?

Tags: python, error-403

cuando uso yt-dlp con 'default_search':'auto' y busco canciones la mayoría de las veces me lo descarga pero en algunas canciones me salta el siguiente error

```
 [download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

no sé si importa mucho pero lo estoy usando en un bot de discord si quieren más informacion del error diganme y lo mando porque no me deja mandarlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: igual ya lo pude resolver muchas gracias.